# Building GitLab projects with Terraform

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I'm attempting to build out a GitLab project/repo in Terraform using the built in Terraform provider "[GitLab](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/index.html)".  It seems quite straight forward but I'm unexpectedly getting the following 401 unauthorized error when I `$ terraform plan` my file below.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11.0"
}

provider "gitlab" {
  token = "<valid-token-id>"
}

resource "gitlab_project" "my_repo" {
  name         = "My Repo"
  namespace_id = 85
}

// ERROR RETURNED BELOW
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
* provider.gitlab: GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user: 401 {message: 
401 Unauthorized}
```

I know that the GitLab token that I'm passing into the gitlab `provider` is valid because I receive a valid response when I make the following call:

```
$ curl https://<mycompany>.githost.io/api/v4/projects?private_token=$GITLAB_TOKEN
```

Additionally, that token is from a superuser that has full GitLab access.

I DO realize those are two separate endpoints it's hitting for the successful `curl` call and the `terraform plan` call.  Is there a way for me to configure what endpoint Terraform hits when it plans/applies?  Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Pretty sure that's defaulting to using gitlab.com rather than the older style githost.io (I don't think this is offered any more but might be wrong here). You should also set the `base_url` in the provider definition unless you're setting it via environment variables?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks [ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor)!!

I'm a big dummy.  All I needed was the `base_url` to be specified (ALL the way out including the `/api/v4/`).

```
provider "gitlab" {
  token    = "<valid-token>"
  base_url = "https://<mycompany>.githost.io/api/v4/"
}
```

Epic high five to you.

Answer (score 1):

thx for post this entry, from my side it worked as below:

```
provider "gitlab" {
  token = var.gitlab_token
  base_url = "https://<gitlab_server>/api/v4/"
}
```

tested with the following version provider:

```
gitlab = {
  source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
  version = "15.8.0"
}
```

hope it can be useful.